# BalanceOf from BasicToken & totalSupply from ERC20Basic not working from Crowdsale.sol

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, inheritance, crowdsale

I'm using Crowdsale.sol from [OpenZeppelin / zeppelin-solidity](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol).  Here's a snippet:

```
import '../token/MintableToken.sol';
import '../math/SafeMath.sol';

/**
 * @title Crowdsale 
 * @dev Crowdsale is a base contract for managing a token crowdsale.
 * Crowdsales have a start and end block, where investors can make
 * token purchases and the crowdsale will assign them tokens based
 * on a token per ETH rate. Funds collected are forwarded to a wallet 
 * as they arrive.
 */
contract Crowdsale {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  // The token being sold
  MintableToken public token;
```

Is this inheriting from MintableToken?

MintableToken.sol inherits from StandardToken.sol and Ownable.sol.  StandardToken.sol inherits from BasicToken.sol and ERC20.sol.  BasicToken.sol inherits from ERC20Basic.sol and SafeMath.sol.

I want to use `function balanceOf` from BasicToken.sol and `uint256 public totalSupply` from ERC20Basic.sol, but these do not appear on [remix.ethereum.org](https://remix.ethereum.org) (using "JavaScript VM") after creating the Crowdsale contract .

If I change Crowdsale.sol to any of the following:

```
contract Crowdsale is StandardToken {

contract Crowdsale is MintableToken {

contract Crowdsale is BasicToken {
```

...`balanceOf` and `totalSupply` appear (after creating contract), but they only return 0. I send some funds to the contract and enter the sender's address into `balanceOf` and it returns 0.  I click on `totalSupply` and it returns zero.  They do not seem to be working.

What do I need to do to get these to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding that class. From the looks of it Crowdsale.sol is a token factory.  It will take payment to generate a MintableToken contract dynamically.

You would then need to access the newly minted Token to access the actual token functions.

Comment: How do I access these Token functions and variables (balanceOf, transfer, totalSupply) from:  1) remix 2) wallet ?  In remix, do I need to create MintableToken contract as well as Crowdsale contract, so that I can access them through the MintableToken contract?